# Verifying a live video stream periodically

Tags: rtmp, http-live-streaming

I would like to be able to automatically verify that a live video stream (RTMP or HLS) is running so I can set up a notifier when it's down.

Something like this, but for video:

$ curl -Is http://www.google.com | head -1

Does anyone know of any command line tools that can do this? VLC and youtube-dl work but seem a little heavy handed for this task. Maybe RTMPDUMP?

Comment: Have you checked searching on serverfault: http://serverfault.com/questions/270634/how-can-i-verify-that-an-rtmp-stream-url-is-working

Comment: @Alam Awesome, thanks for that link!